# Keycode trigger on enter key not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I'm using `keycode` to trigger a button click on enter. I have the following, which is working when an alert is placed in they keycode function, but not when placed in the `.click(function...`. Not sure what I'm missing to get the keycode to trigger the ajax call. It is currently just pushing `?imageid=750` to the end of the query string in the URL.

```
//force use of only numerical input
$('#imageid').keyup(function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          alert($("#imageid").val());
        //event.preventDefault();
        $('.image-search').trigger('click');
    }
});



$('.image-search').click( function () {
    var root = "http://localhost:7777/proxy/staging/rest/v1/cms/story/id/";
    //CLEAR IMAGE ID VALUE FROM PREVIOUS ENTRIES
    $("#imageid").val('');
    var encodeID = $("#imageid").val();
    var bearerToken = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');

    //IF TESTING ON LOCALHOST
    if (document.domain == 'localhost') {
        url = root + encodeID + "/images";
    } else {
        //IF IN PRODUCTION
        url = "/cropper/admin/cropv2/rest/v1/cms/story/id/" + encodeID + "/images";
        //GRAB REFERRER URL FOR ASSET ID
        //STRIP OUT ASSET ID, MATCH BUT DON'T INCLUDE 'ASSETS' AND SET SUCCESEEDING VALUE AS ASSET ID
        var regexp = /assets\/(\d+)/;
        var assetid = regexp.exec(window.document.referrer);
        $("#imageid").val(assetid[1]);
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": bearerToken
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        var obj = response;
        $("#imageid").css("border-color", "#ccc");
        $(".search-results").empty();
        for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
            if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                $(".search-results").append($("<li><a href='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "' target='_blank'><div class='thumbnail'><img width='30' height='30' src='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "' target='_blank'/></img><div class='caption'><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></div></a></li>"));
            }
        }
        //$(".search-results").append("<div class='caption'>" + data.id + "</div><div class='thumbnail'><img width='40' height='40' src='" + data.thumbnailUrl + "'/></img>").css("float", "left");
    }).fail(function (data) {
        $(".search-results").empty();
        $(".search-results").append("<p class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid ID</p>");
        $("#imageid").css("border-color", "red");
    });
});
});
```

But when implemented into the full project, it no longer works correctly. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Using this fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4uwaz2yd/36/), and removing lines 1-173, the trigger works correctly. With the lines included, it seems to be blocked.

Comment: Check console, fix error. Then does it fix your issue?

Comment: If I had any errors in the console, it might...but no issues in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, you are having other Javascript errors present that are causing the script to stop.

Also Try `$('.image-search').click();` instead of `$('.image-search').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 0):

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: ImglyKit is not defined
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null (fileInput)

Comment: ImglyKit being included or not is irrelevant to the issue I'm having. I just need to be able to trigger the form click on enter key. This can be done on its own, but its being blocked by something else.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xccutryw/
(No ImglyKit and one fileinput, and it's working)

Comment: it looks like the culprit is having the `<form id="fileUpload"  class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">` `</form>` encapsulating the fields. The issue is that I have a file input field, so I need to have this in place.